# Error while uploading image using image picker in emulator - Flutter app

Tags: android, android-emulator

Please how can I fix this error? I use the image picker but when I select the image in the gallery from the emulator it doesn't appear.

Here is the complete error text :

> D/EGL_emulation(19810): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa70bcb40: ver 2 0 (tinfo
> 0x9395e330)
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(19810): Google Play services out of date for
> com.example.chat_app.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470
>
> I/art     (19810): Do partial code cache collection, code=22KB,
> data=30KB I/art     (19810): After code cache collection, code=20KB,
> data=30KB I/art     (19810): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
>
> D/EGL_emulation(19810): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa70bc3c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo
> 0xa70c0bd0) D/EGL_emulation(19810): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa70bc3c0: ver 2
> 0 (tinfo 0xa70c0bd0) D/EGL_emulation(19810): eglMakeCurrent:
> 0xa70bcb40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9395e330)
>
> E/flutter (19810): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'File?' in
> type cast E/flutter (19810): #0
> _UserImagePickerState._pickedImage. (package:chat_app/widgets/pickers/user_image_picker.dart:19:37)
> E/flutter (19810): #1      State.setState
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1121:30) E/flutter
> (19810): #2      _UserImagePickerState._pickedImage
> (package:chat_app/widgets/pickers/user_image_picker.dart:18:5)
> E/flutter (19810):  E/flutter (19810):

Answer (score 1):

I think, that this string: "Google Play services out of date for com.example.chat_app. Requires 12451000 but found 11743470" says about use out of dated version of Android needed to using widget.

try to use newer version of Android in your emulator.